# How to call Objective C method(which is the return protocol) in Swift Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I had implemented static library which is written in Objective C language, in new Swift Project. Everything is fine and I can call a class method and instance method in swift code block successfully. But when I try to call a method which is return protocol, I get an error. I have not been calling successfully below method in swift code.

Anyone know how can I call this method in Swift.

Static library which is written with Objective C
[image: All methods is here]

I can not call a method which name is getScreenManager. Also,  Xcode is not showing hint for this method in Swift.
[image]

IScreenManager is below.

```
 @protocol IScreenManager <NSObject>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ScreenManagerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *transitionDictionary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *loadingImages;
@property CGFloat loadingAnimationDuration;
@property CGFloat loadingBackgroundAlpha;

- (void)showViewsWithObject:(id)object withMessage:(Response *)message;
- (void)enableScreen;
- (void)disableScreenWillShowLoadingView:(BOOL)willShow;
- (int)getActiveViewId;

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground;
- (void)applicationDidEnterForeground;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground;
```

Comment: Please post your code as *text,* not screenshots. Add all relevant definitions (such as the protocol), and remove unrelated stuff. In other words: make it a [mcve]!

Comment: Hi @MartinR , i can not paste code to here because of bank code security violation. Sorry about that. But my post is simple. i can not call  - (id <IScreenManager>)getScreenManager  method in swift.

Comment: And posting your code as screenshot is no security violation??? You don't have to (and should not) post *all* your code, just enough that someone else can reproduce the problem.– Anyway, I cannot reproduce your problem, it works for me.

Comment: i shared a restricted screenshot not whole code snapped. But anyway thank you. Maybe Xcode 9 caused this problem. i will share when i find solution.

Comment: What *object* do you want to call the method on?

Comment: i edit question. @MartinR

Answer (score 2):

if you are using swift 3 or later, then try for a method screenManager as there are lot of naming convention changes in swift 3. And due to this objective-c function calling from swift also affects.

[Click here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) to read more

Comment: Thank you for information @Amit . But i am using swift 4 and Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution. i think, this is a kind of Xcode GM bug. Because i did now how to call this method and i expected Xcode will show hint just like other method.. When i write below code section, Xcode not fired error and build and run successfully. Now i am downloading Xcode 9. Thank all for fast response.

```
 override func getScreenManager() -> IScreenManager! {
    return MultiLayerScreenManager();
}
```